# How can I keybind the fly navigation camera in 2.8?

Tags: interface

The fly navigation tool exists in 2.8 Beta, but is only accessible via Search. (This surprises me because it seems pretty finished.) I use it a lot and would like to have quick access to it. In particular, I use it to take videos of work in progress for vlogging, and having to call it with search really puts a crimp in that.

I have looked for it in the Preferences > Keymap section, but I don't see it. I tried under 3dView(Global), I don't see it there. There is a section for View3D Fly Modal, but it only shows how to control it once it is active, not how to start it.

It seems like it must be in there somewhere. Am I missing it somehow? Can I keybind it if it indeed isn't there?

Comment: It called "View Navigation".

Comment: @FFeller Where is that? I don't see it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
It is in View>Navigation>Fly Navigation

Right click And you have "Assign Shorcut" in menu

Comment: Oh, i see - you can right click on that and call that menu. I didn't realize that. Thanks. - You should really add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Newer releases have restored a default keybind for the this navigation:

For non german keyboard layouts the shortcut should be <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>``</kbd>  where <kbd>`</kbd> is a [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

and <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>  for german keyboard.

If it doesn't work please check that you are using a recent version of blender.

As per https://developer.blender.org/T55194.

Comment: For easy understanding I call such combinations Shift ~ (Tilda)