# Moving camera around in camera view in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, camera, workflow

In Blender 2.79b, you can move around in the camera view by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  When I tried it in Blender 2.8, it doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone know how to do this in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 8):

You can link the camera to the viewport and then rotate/pan/zoom as you are used to from the viewport - very handy!
Just

- press N tp show right menu
- view tab
- view accordeon
- view lock accordeon
- check "lock camera to view"

All credits to [this guy on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZxJo9IPVCM)...

Answer (score 4):

Fly and walk navigation have no default shortcut.
In the view menu select fly or walk.

[image]

To navigate:

> Move the mouse left/right to pan the view left/right or move it up/down to tilt the view up/down.
>
> Move the camera forward/backward <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.
>
> left/right <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>.
>   Jump <kbd>V</kbd> – only in gravity mode.
>
> Move up and down <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> – only in free mode.
>
> Alternate between free and gravity modes <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> or <kbd>G</kbd>.
>
> Change the movement speed: - <kbd>WheelUp</kbd> or <kbd>NumpadPlus</kbd> to increase the movement speed for this open session. - <kbd>WheelDown</kbd> or 
>   <kbd>NumpadMinus</kbd> to decrease the movement speed for this open session. -
>
> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> (hold) – to speed up the movement temporarily. - <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> (hold) – to slow down the movement temporarily.

Comment: Read also: [How can I keybind the fly navigation camera in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140841/how-can-i-keybind-the-fly-navigation-camera-in-2-8)

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the "has no default keybind" assumption,

For non german keyboard layouts the shortcut should be <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>``</kbd>  where <kbd>`</kbd> is a [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

and <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>  for german keyboard.

If it doesn't work please check that you are using a recent version of blender.

As per https://developer.blender.org/T55194.

Comment: To be more like other 3D software I map this to a mouse button: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187570/101687

Answer (score 0):

Go to the view tab then go to navigation then right click under walk navigation then press change short cut and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and make sure it works. you should be able to move around like you could in blender 2.7

Comment: Hi there :). Use the answer section to provide simple and detailed answer. Take a tour to understand how this site works - https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I used to use flight mode a lot and Blender changed the shortcut.

For 2.8+ the new shortcut for *Fly Mode* is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd>